# Django Rest Framework Postman Token Authentication

Tags: django, rest, curl, django-rest-framework, postman

I am using Django Rest Framework Token authentication and if i do `curl http://localhost:8000/api/v1/users/?format=json -H 'Authorization: Token 0a813fdcd3f8846d6fa376f2592bbc678b0b8e85'` everything works fine.

But when i try to achieve that with Postman chrome client it nothing happens. What am i doing wrong??

[image]

Comment: does removing format=json on the end fix anything it seems unecessary if postman is already sending the content-type in the headers.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You are setting the header to `Authorization: Token` when it really should just be `Authorization`. The header is actually just `Authorization`, but the value is `Token [token_string]`, where `[token_string]` is the authorization token that you have obtained.

Comment: Make sure your value is `Token` followed by a space, followed by the actual token as specified in this answer (which is correct).

Answer (score 3):

[image]For the new version of postman it is necessary to choose Auth 2 type authentication in the left panel, then in the right panel, specify the DRf key which is "Token" and in the value the token itself.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the above answer, make sure to enable "Follow Authorization header" under setting (See below screenshot)
[image]

Answer (score 0):

After Specifying Authorization and Token value try to add the token in an environment so that every time you don't have to copy the token value.

Answer (score 0):

After get access token from `http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/login/`

such this :

```
{
    "email": "user@example.com",
    "tokens": {
        "refresh": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ0b2tlbl90eXBlIjoicmVmcmVzaCIsImV4cCI6MTY2NjI2NTAxMSwiaWF0IjoxNjY2MTc4NjExLCJqdGkiOiJjZWM3MzJmNDZkMGE0MTNjOTE3ODM5ZGYxNzRiNzMxZCIsInVzZXJfaWQiOjcwfQ.5Rd25s6msp72IHyU1BxE4ym24YIEbhyFsBdUztGXz0I",
        "access": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ0b2tlbl90eXBlIjoiYWNjZXNzIiwiZXhwIjoxNjY2MjY1MDExLCJpYXQiOjE2NjYxNzg2MTEsImp0aSI6IjgyOWFmZGE5MWY2ODRhNDZhMDllZGMzMmI0NmY0Mzg5IiwidXNlcl9pZCI6NzB9.TYhi0INai293ljc5zBk59Hwet-m9a1Mc1CtA56BEE_8"
    },
    "id": 70
}
```

copy content of "access" key in response, then in post man in Headers add new item by key : `Authorization` and value such this:

`Bearer eyJ0eXAi....`

that eyJ0eXAi.... is value of access key.

[image]

then send the request.